# Crud com php ajax

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, crud

tenho uma tabela que quero personaliza e deixa-lá um crud completo, com delete, insert, update e delete múltiplos registros, 1- queria ver se poderia deixa essa tabela compatível com jquery 2.2.0 ou um jquery mais avançado pois ele so aceita o 1.8.1, eu consegui inserir o php com while na td, mas o pesquisa não busca em todas as paginas da tabela, só pesquisa na pagina onde os registro esta a amostra, ou seja, eu tenho que da next para pesquisa na outra pagina!

```
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.tablesorter.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.tablesorter.pager.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="custom.css" media="screen" />



    <form method="post" action="../melhorando-exibicao-tabelas-jquery/exemplo.html" id="frm-filtro">
  <p>
    <label for="pesquisar">Pesquisar</label>
    <input type="text" id="pesquisar" name="pesquisar" size="30" />
  </p>
</form>

<table cellspacing="0" summary="Tabela de dados fictícios">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th><input type="checkbox" value="1" id="marcar-todos" name="marcar-todos" /></th>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Nome</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <?php
    require_once 'dbconfig.php';
    $conn = Conexao::getInstance();
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM tb_cidades ORDER BY id DESC");
    $stmt->execute();
    while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        ?>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" value="1" name="marcar[]" /></td>
                <td><?= $row['id']; ?></td>
      <td><?= $row['nome']; ?></td>

    </tr>
    <?php
    }
    ?> 
  </tbody>
</table>

<div id="pager" class="pager">
    <form>
            <span>
                Exibir <select class="pagesize">
                        <option selected="selected"  value="10">10</option>
                        <option value="20">20</option>
                        <option value="30">30</option>
                        <option  value="40">40</option>
                </select> registros
            </span>

            <img src="first.png" class="first"/>
        <img src="prev.png" class="prev"/>
        <input type="text" class="pagedisplay"/>
        <img src="next.png" class="next"/>
        <img src="last.png" class="last"/>
    </form>
</div>

<script>
$(function(){

  $('table > tbody > tr:odd').addClass('odd');

  $('table > tbody > tr').hover(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('hover');
  });

  $('#marcar-todos').click(function(){
    $('table > tbody > tr > td > :checkbox')
      .attr('checked', $(this).is(':checked'))
      .trigger('change');
  });

  $('table > tbody > tr > td > :checkbox').bind('click change', function(){
    var tr = $(this).parent().parent();
    if($(this).is(':checked')) $(tr).addClass('selected');
    else $(tr).removeClass('selected');
  });

  $('form').submit(function(e){ e.preventDefault(); });

  $('#pesquisar').keydown(function(){
    var encontrou = false;
    var termo = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $('table > tbody > tr').each(function(){
      $(this).find('td').each(function(){
        if($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(termo) > -1) encontrou = true;
      });
      if(!encontrou) $(this).hide();
      else $(this).show();
      encontrou = false;
    });
  });

  $("table") 
    .tablesorter({
      dateFormat: 'uk',
      headers: {
        0: {
          sorter: false
        },
        5: {
          sorter: false
        }
      }
    }) 
    .tablesorterPager({container: $("#pager")})
    .bind('sortEnd', function(){
      $('table > tbody > tr').removeClass('odd');
      $('table > tbody > tr:odd').addClass('odd');
    });

});
</script>
```

jquery.tablesorter.pager.js

```
(function($) {
    $.extend({
        tablesorterPager: new function() {

            function updatePageDisplay(c) {
                var s = $(c.cssPageDisplay,c.container).val((c.page+1) + c.seperator + c.totalPages);   
            }

            function setPageSize(table,size) {
                var c = table.config;
                c.size = size;
                c.totalPages = Math.ceil(c.totalRows / c.size);
                c.pagerPositionSet = false;
                moveToPage(table);
                fixPosition(table);
            }

            function fixPosition(table) {
                var c = table.config;
                if(!c.pagerPositionSet && c.positionFixed) {
                    var c = table.config, o = $(table);
                    if(o.offset) {
                        c.container.css({
                            top: o.offset().top + o.height() + 'px',
                            position: 'absolute'
                        });
                    }
                    c.pagerPositionSet = true;
                }
            }

            function moveToFirstPage(table) {
                var c = table.config;
                c.page = 0;
                moveToPage(table);
            }

            function moveToLastPage(table) {
                var c = table.config;
                c.page = (c.totalPages-1);
                moveToPage(table);
            }

            function moveToNextPage(table) {
                var c = table.config;
                c.page++;
                if(c.page >= (c.totalPages-1)) {
                    c.page = (c.totalPages-1);
                }
                moveToPage(table);
            }

            function moveToPrevPage(table) {
                var c = table.config;
                c.page--;
                if(c.page <= 0) {
                    c.page = 0;
                }
                moveToPage(table);
            }


            function moveToPage(table) {
                var c = table.config;
                if(c.page < 0 || c.page > (c.totalPages-1)) {
                    c.page = 0;
                }

                renderTable(table,c.rowsCopy);
            }

            function renderTable(table,rows) {

                var c = table.config;
                var l = rows.length;
                var s = (c.page * c.size);
                var e = (s + c.size);
                if(e > rows.length ) {
                    e = rows.length;
                }


                var tableBody = $(table.tBodies[0]);

                // clear the table body

                $.tablesorter.clearTableBody(table);

                for(var i = s; i < e; i++) {

                    //tableBody.append(rows[i]);

                    var o = rows[i];
                    var l = o.length;
                    for(var j=0; j < l; j++) {

                        tableBody[0].appendChild(o[j]);

                    }
                }

                fixPosition(table,tableBody);

                $(table).trigger("applyWidgets");

                if( c.page >= c.totalPages ) {
                    moveToLastPage(table);
                }

                updatePageDisplay(c);
            }

            this.appender = function(table,rows) {

                var c = table.config;

                c.rowsCopy = rows;
                c.totalRows = rows.length;
                c.totalPages = Math.ceil(c.totalRows / c.size);

                renderTable(table,rows);
            };

            this.defaults = {
                size: 10,
                offset: 0,
                page: 0,
                totalRows: 0,
                totalPages: 0,
                container: null,
                cssNext: '.next',
                cssPrev: '.prev',
                cssFirst: '.first',
                cssLast: '.last',
                cssPageDisplay: '.pagedisplay',
                cssPageSize: '.pagesize',
                seperator: "/",
                positionFixed: true,
                appender: this.appender
            };

            this.construct = function(settings) {

                return this.each(function() {   

                    config = $.extend(this.config, $.tablesorterPager.defaults, settings);

                    var table = this, pager = config.container;

                    $(this).trigger("appendCache");

                    config.size = parseInt($(".pagesize",pager).val());

                    $(config.cssFirst,pager).click(function() {
                        moveToFirstPage(table);
                        return false;
                    });
                    $(config.cssNext,pager).click(function() {
                        moveToNextPage(table);
                        return false;
                    });
                    $(config.cssPrev,pager).click(function() {
                        moveToPrevPage(table);
                        return false;
                    });
                    $(config.cssLast,pager).click(function() {
                        moveToLastPage(table);
                        return false;
                    });
                    $(config.cssPageSize,pager).change(function() {
                        setPageSize(table,parseInt($(this).val()));
                        return false;
                    });
                });
            };

        }
    });
    // extend plugin scope
    $.fn.extend({
        tablesorterPager: $.tablesorterPager.construct
    });

})(jQuery);
```

alguém tem uma ideia como fazer?

Comment: Rapaz acho que entendi sua questão, existem alguns plugins que fazem a tabela funcionar para pesquisa e listar as consultas. Confere esse link https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/zero_configuration.html vc faz a consulta normal em php e a tabela vai listar organizando o frontend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> só pesquisa na pagina onde os registro esta a amostra, ou seja, eu
>   tenho que da next para pesquisa na outra pagina!

Isso é assim mesmo cara, pois a pesquisa está apenas no FrontEnd. Você tem que fazer essa pesquisa no **backend**.

Para isso, vc deve usar um plugin que aceite filtro com ajax, veja:

https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-pager-ajax.html